# Rails application failing to start session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is a really strange issue I am running into. When I start my rails app and go to 0.0.0.0:3000 and open the console when I try to set a cookie -

```
cookies[:foo] = "bar"
```

I can log it out using pry, but when I check the resources tab or try to access the cookie nothing is getting set.

To test and ensure things I made a new project and started it up, upon visiting a page and checking the resources tab I see that the session gets set right away.

Any ideas on what could cause the session to fail starting?

Answer (score 0):

So after going through my gem file and going through each gem. The answer was 'Rails-Api' gem. Seems to block all session and cookies. By removing that everything works again.